# MediaPlayer is not looping

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to create activity background music, but `MediaPlayer` playing not repeatedly :(
Why my `MediaPlayer` is not looping?

There is my code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tersetetete);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(8f, 8f);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` with the line `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon);` that you wrote below.

You are having the issues because `new MediaPlayer();` creates a new `MediaPlayer` object on which you set Volume and Looping properties, but after that you're creating a new object with `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon);` and then you play the sound represented by that new object which doesn't have any looping property set to true nor any volume of 8f 8f.

Here's the full code you can use:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tersetetete);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(.8f, .8f);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: If I want to set other Res audio file, Have I must reCreate the `mediaPlayer`

Comment: Every sound you want to play will be an object in your memory. If you don't need fon sound anymore, you can do `mediaPlayer.release();` after it plays and then assign the next created object to the `mediaPlayer` reference. To create the object, use the same  `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.otherSound);` for each sound you need to play.

Comment: mediaPlayer.setVolume(8f, 8f);                                                                  the passed volume values should be in range 0.0 to 1.0 ,why you used 8f

Comment: @AnbaraAyoub: I was using the same values as the poster. Adding period before each makes more sense though. I will update my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

call

```
 mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

after

```
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: how did you know that?

Answer (score 1):

I am on KITKAT and setlooping(true) was not working for me, so I made this changes and now it works...

```
                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
                //Stop on going Music
                AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService("audio");
                if (audiomanager.isMusicActive())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
                    intent.putExtra("command", "pause");
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
                //Setting Max Volume
                audiomanager.setStreamVolume(3, audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(3), 0);
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(),R.raw.file);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                //This did the trick
                mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaplayer, int i, int j)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

And to stop I have used.

```
               mMediaPlayer.release();
```