# MediaPlayer is not looping setting setLooping(true);

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm not able to undestrand why this mediaplayer is not looping on my android phone.
when player.start(); is called the ringtone is played only once.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaPlayer is not looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515455/mediaplayer-is-not-looping)

Comment: Which device are you using? I tried the same code on Nexus 5 and it's working as expected.

Comment: I'm using a nexus 5, the sound is reproduced only once